# Coolant leak which just won't quit

Tags: buick, coolant-leak, water-pump, century

Car is 2003 Buick century.one owner now 89. Very Well maintained. I have had all hoses changed. Plus water pump, head gasket and lastly radiator. Still leaks with me getting about a mile from home and red light comes on and I have to return home. Help me.

Comment: Leaks coolant I assume, but from where?  Identify where it's leaking from and correct that problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Like jwh20 is trying to say, I think you need to track the leak to its home and this is going to help you figure out what you need to do next.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Apparently, your well maintained car wasn't maintained by experts despite the numerous parts they replaced on your dime otherwise this problem would be solved.  Perhaps visiting another repair shop with more expertise may find the problem. One simple method of cooling system troubleshooting would be using a hand held tool to pressurize the (cold engine) cooling system with a pressure gauge to system specs then examine the entire cooling system for leaks. Testing the pressure cap too, to reveal whether it's worn out or not.